# Kivy: Loading AsyncImage second time raises ReferenceError

Tags: python, kivy, weak-references

I'm using a real-time database(**Firebase**) that stores image URLs (and other items), my app fetches the data from the database and displays it on some Widgets. Can't post all the code here coz it's very long.

My AsyncImage class goes like this:

```
...
class MyAsyncImage(AsyncImage):
    def __int__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyAsyncImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.set_image_source, 1/30)

    def set_image_source(self, dt):
        self.source = itemArray[3] #The image url is stored in this array
...
```

then inside my .kv file I have:

```
<ViewContent@RelativeLayout>:
    ...
    GridLayout:
        spacing: 10
        cols: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 100

        MyAsyncImage:
            size: self.texture_size
            pos: self.pos
```

the code works only once, I'm able to search for an item and then display its contents (including the image) on my widgets. When I go back and search for a different item, the updated contents do appear on the widgets as normal...but loading the image raises a ***ReferenceError***(*weakly-referenced object no longer exists*)

What doesn't make sense to me is that I have a similar code for updating the text of the labels, and it works just fine no matter how many times I search for a different item, here's the code:

```
class FirstLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (.7, None)
        self.height = 60
        self.markup = True
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.set_text, 1/30)


    def set_text(self, dt):
        if itemArray[0] != "":
            self.text =  itemArray[0] #this works
```

I've tried making a strong ref using the `id.__self__`  method, it doesn't work. Also, defining an accessor method that returns the source and then setting `source: self.get_image_source()` in the .kv file, works...but only once. Then I get the **ReferenceError**. Even adding and then removing the AsyncImage widget produces the same results...same error. This is causing me a serious headache.

Any kind of help would be appreciated, I've been searching for a solution for quite some time now...with no luck. And I can't proceed with my project if the error persists. Please help.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you  setting the source 30 times per second?

Comment: @JohnAnderson please refer to the gif image on this link https://imgur.com/a/acD1Yqo to see how I did the whole thing. I couldn't figure out another way of updating the image. Have any suggestions

Comment: If you set an `AsyncImage.source` to a `gif` animation, it should display the animation without further action on your part. The speed of the animation is controlled by `anim_delay` of `Image`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.anim_delay).

Comment: I created that gif animation to show how my app interface looks like. What you're seeing is my 'SearchScreen@Screen', which has 'BackButton@Button', 'TopLabel@Label' (the one written "Find a room"), 'SearchInput@TextInput' and 'SearchButton@Button'. After typing a string on the text input and pressing the search button, results are fetched from Firebase and stored to an array, then a new widget 'ViewButton@Button' is added to 'SearchScreen@Screen' . This button shows 3 items from the array (Location, Type, Price). Clicking on this button takes you to the 'ViewScreen@Screen'.

Comment: The view screen then displays all items from the array accordingly. This is where I'm facing a problem because 'ViewScreen' displays results according to what you searched for in 'SearchScreen'. The image urls (and all the other items) inside the array are not static, they change after you 'search' for something...so do the widgets in 'ViewScreen'. The AsyncImage widget is the only issue, it doesn't wanna update...instead it raises a ReferenceError.

Comment: There must be a problem elsewhere in your code. Add a `print` to show exactly what you are passing to `AsyncImage` for the `source`. Note that this works fine for me: `AsyncImage(source='https://i.imgur.com/dNYRAQj.gif')`.

Comment: Got it, the array where I store the image URLs wasn't updating because I was using  `itemArray = []` instead of `itemArray.clear()` to empty it. Silly mistake I know. It's all fixed now. Thanks a lot for your time and for shedding some light on the matter Mr Anderson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in Kivy when using Python >= 3.8.

It has been fixed in the codebase.

There are several ways to fix it:

- update Kivy to 2.0.0rc3 or later
- downgrade the Python you're using to version < 3.8
- manually edit the kivy code (here's the specific change: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/6595/files)

More details here:
https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1089